# Оператор return завершает работу цикла. Как можно исправить код в моём случае?

Tags: python

Вот мой код:

```
def SWHL_command():
    response = requests.get("http://www.swhl.ru/tournament/1026071/teams")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    commands_names = soup.find_all("a", class_="teams__name-link")
    for commands_name in commands_names:
        c = commands_name.text.strip()
        return c

print(SWHL_command())
```

Ожидаемый мною результат:

```
Hockey Dads
Red Tigers
Silk Way Star
Варяг-2
```

Но на деле результат следующий:

```
Hockey Dads
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: сохранять в список. вернуть этот список из функции.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно заносить данные в список, а потом уже вытаскивать из него.

```
my_list = []
for commands_names in commands_names:
    my_list.append(commands_names.text.strip())
return my_list
```

Answer (score 4):

Надо сохранить результат и вернуть по завершению цикла:

```
def SWHL_command():
    response = requests.get("http://www.swhl.ru/tournament/1026071/teams")
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")
    commands_names = soup.find_all("a", class_="teams__name-link")
    res = list()
    for commands_name in commands_names:
        c = commands_name.text.strip()
        res.append(c)
    return res

print(SWHL_command())
```

Answer (score 0):

Решение с использованием PEP:

```py
return [x.text.strip() for x in commands_names]
```